# New module in magento not updating layout

Tags: xml, layout, magento

I am trying to create a new custom module in magento but the layout is not loading. It always load three column layout which is defined as a default in page.xml file. I think it is not considering the layout set for my module action even if it is mentioned in the config.xml file like this-

```
<frontend>
        <routers>
            <mynamespace_test>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mynamespace_Test</module>
                    <frontName>test</frontName>
                </args>
            </mynamespace_test>
        </routers>  
  <layout>
          <updates>
              <test><file>test.xml</file></test>
          </updates>
      </layout>
    </frontend>
```

and my test.xml looks like this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <test_index_index translate="label">
        <label>Test module</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>     
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="test/this" name="test.this" template="test/test.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </test_index_index>
</layout>
```

and my controller is defined like this:-

```
class mynamespace_Test_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
 function indexAction()
 {
  $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
 }

}
```

Please help! what I am missing.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I got it working. I understood the problem is not there with layout file after pointing the layout file of some other module. The thing is wrong with this is  mentioning namespace while defining router for module:

I updated this block of code:-

```
<routers>
            <mynamespace_test>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mynamespace_Test</module>
                    <frontName>test</frontName>
                </args>
            </mynamespace_test>
        </routers>
```

to

```
<routers>
            <test>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mynamespace_Test</module>
                    <frontName>test</frontName>
                </args>
            </test>
        </routers>
```

and it worked fine.

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of changing `namespace_test` to `test` in config.xml you could have also changed `test_index_index` to `namespace_test_index_index` in your layout file. There is something similar already in effect with the admin pages, their URLs all start with `admin` but their layouts are `adminhtml`.

Comment: Thank you. Just spent the last half hour banging my head against the wall

Answer (score 2):

Where have you saved `test.xml`?  It needs to be in the currently active theme:

```
app/design/frontend/default/activetheme/layout/test.xml
```

I also recommend that you install the LayoutViewer extension from Alan Storm's blog so that you can debug which of your xml updates are being inserted into the layout.

Comment: Now I changed layout file in config.xml. I set it to <layout>
          <updates>
              <test><file>customer.xml</file></test>
          </updates>
      </layout>  and added the block code from test.xml to customer.xml And it is still not working. Something is still wrong